# How can I filter on result of aggregate functions like min, max, sum?

Tags: postgresql, query

In the below query:

```
SELECT user_id, (max(ts) -  min(ts)) as tsdiff
               FROM analytics 
               GROUP BY user_id
```

How can I filter on  on `tsdiff` which I assume is a `interval`? For example I'd like to filter for all records where `tsdiff` is larger than `1d` (one day).

Even if I were to use a subquery, I'd face the same issue again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
  user_id
 ,(max(ts) -  min(ts)) as tsdiff
FROM 
  analytics 
GROUP BY 
  user_id
HAVING
  max(ts) -  min(ts) > interval '1 day'
```

See:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html